# In the context of risk-averse multi-stage programming and scheduling of resources consumption, is it always optimum to most risky resource first?

Tags: optimization, multi-stage

In the case of multiple stages with risk averse decision maker, there can be a decision situation where multiple resources has to be scheduled for consumption. These resources can have varying degree of risk associated with them, e.g., if you have two dishes and you want to decide which one you should eat first, you may want to eat the dish which has more chance of deterioration (if we assume no other factors like shortsightedness, taste preferences etc. will effect the decision).
This will prevent risk propagation to future time periods and make the overall solution of risk-averse optimization surly optimum give this decision will not effect cost etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It depends on the data and how you quantify risk.

Consider two products `A` and `B` with costs:

|  | t=1 | t=2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | `-1` | `-0.95` |
| B | `-1` | `{-1 w.p. 0.99, -0 w.p. 0.01}` |

A then B gives:
`{-2 w.p. 0.99, -1 w.p. 0.01}`

B then A gives:
`{-1.95 w.p. 1.0} = -1.95`

If we want to minimize costs, then in expectation, you'd pick A then B for a cost of -1.99.

To maximize the worst-case cost, you'd pick B then A for a cost of -1.95.

If you use a risk measure like CVaR:
`CVaRₐ(x) = min_z { z + 1 / (1 - α) * E[(xᵢ - z)₊] }`

then if α is 0 the optimal choice is A then B and lim α -> 1 is B then A.
There's a cross over point at α = 0.2 where things are equal.